# array with surfcurve

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to array a door mesh along a curved wall (nurbs) but its array modifier doesn't accept my surfcurve as an input. is there a way to point the modifier to the curve data? this seems to be approaching the need for some parametrization of sorts..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you convert your NURBS curve to mesh or standard curve and then just array that? Assuming you need to maintain the nurbs curve though?

Comment: when I select the surface and try to convert to curve, nothing happens. What I really need is to link the wall to a separate curve so that when I change one, they both update and the array updates as well.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on what you're looking to do. Can you please embed some images in your post along with posting your .blend file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=O4SeRxnP" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/O4SeRxnP/)

okay, heres the file and an image showing the door which I would like to array on this wall.

https://imgur.com/a/jVoYuFM

Comment: Please embed the images in your post as outlined here: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

And do the same for your blend file. It needs to be added to the main post.

Comment: You haven't shared your file, it is not a link  ;)

Comment: ok ok lol here it is